# What is GCC lto wrapper?

Tags: gcc, compilation, wrapper, cross-compiling, lto

I am using buildroot to prepare images for embedded system. I want to export buildroots internal cross compiler so others can use same version, After command checking GCC version: `arm-linux-gcc -v`I see configured `COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER` to static location on my HDD

```
 COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/user/arm/buildroot/output/host/usr/libexec/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.7.1/lto-wrapper
```

It will not be correct on another system.

I was only able to find that LTO means Link Time Optimization. Can you please explain what is lto wrapper used for and when is needed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

‫Whe‬n you compile an executable, gcc will optimize and merge same constants only for the current file. Normally, it can't analyze the whole program since the `.o` files are linked with `ld`.

‭‫That's the purpose of [Interprocedural optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization): Compile the whole executable as if it was a single source file, allowing to make the code more static.

There's a problem with this, LD can't really recognize the exported GIMPLES.
‫‫For this purpose ld use the lto plugin(liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0) which calls make or the`lto-wrapper` directly which calls lto1 where each lto1 launch is responsible for producing a 'partition' (see the -flto-partition option and the lto-partitions parameter in gcc’s documentation).